# How to allow a user in a same group chmod a file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a very simple use case, but somehow it's not working.

I have a user **deploy** who belongs to **www-data** group.

When I try to chmod 777 a file, which looks like below, I get a permission error.

```
www-data www-data   31 Jul 26 09:46 f1f839b7e0e635d46129a4c4073e76a9
```

How come I can't change permission when deploy belongs to the same group?

How can I allow deploy to chmod the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix systems, `chmod` is only available to root and the file's owner, regardless of any permissions (neither the file itself, nor the parent directory). You cannot change this.